# enable the SSL on localhost not working on custom ports

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, localhost

I'm trying to enable the SSL on a custom port I added which is 8040 (localhost:8040), I followed a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20) tutorial to do this

I've xampp and I executed the following commands on `xampp\apache\bin` directory

here are the three commands in order

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048

openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key


openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key private.key 
-out certificate.crt -days 36500 -config C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
```

Now I copied the generated files `private.key` and `certificate.crt` and paste them inside this directory `C:\xampp\apache\conf\key` .

I un-commented the lines related to the SSL inside `httpd.conf` file
and Inside the file `httpd-ssl.conf` inside `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`

I added a new directory

```
<VirtualHost *:8040>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public"
ServerName qa-staging.com
ServerAdmin admin@example
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/key/certificate.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/xampp/apache/conf/key/private.key"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

but when I try to open `https:\\localhost:8040` I got

> This site can’t provide a secure connection

[image]

Now, If I added the key and certificate directories to the default port 443

It works fine when I request https:\localhost

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "listen 8040" in httpd.conf.